# Adding different type of validation on multiple UITextField in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using multiple uitextfield in my uitableview row.

for example user can type the range of number in two of these uitextfield.

now how can i handle some validation on entered value in these uitextfield ?

for example uitextfield1 shouldnt be lower 1 and uitextfield2 shouldnt be highter than 100.

this is my old code to set the textfield have only numerical value :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

    return YES;
}
```

and in my **cellForRowAtIndexPath** :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITextField * UTX1 = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UITextField * UTX2 = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UTX1.delegate = self;
UTX2.delegate = self;
```

Comment: If you want only numeric value in textfield then set numeric keypad for that text field that allows only numeric value, no need to check programatically.

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh Bad advice. A user can use an external keyboard or copy and paste. NEVER rely on the keyboard type.

Comment: @rmaddy Good catch in that case have to check it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
      // allow backspace
      if (!string.length)
      {
           return YES;
      }

      // allow digit 0 to 9
      if ([string intValue])
      {
            if(textfield.tag==1){ // First textfield
                 if([string intValue]<1){
                        return NO;
                 }
            }
            else if(textfield.tag==2){ // Second textfield
                 if([string intValue]>100){
                        return NO;
                 }
            }
            return YES;
      }
      return NO;
}
```

You can change conditions for range of value to allow for each textfield as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Validate the textfield based on tag.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

if(textField.tag == 1)
{
return [string isEqualToString:filtered] && [string intValue]> 1 ;
}
if(textfield.tag == 2)
{
return [string isEqualToString:filtered] && [string intValue] < 100;
}
   return YES;
}
```